# bootstrap css layout of irregular tiles - using push and pull

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3.3.2 and ran into a confusing situation. The wanted effect is as shown on a picture below

[image http://imageshack.com/a/img537/8048/MAcoOV.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img537/8048/MAcoOV.png)

My current html looks like this

```
 <div class='container'>

        <div style='padding-bottom: 30px;' class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
          <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
          <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/840x400"></div>
        </div>

        <div style='padding-bottom: 30px;' class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
          <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/840x400"></div>
          <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        </div>

        <div style='padding-bottom: 30px;' class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/840x400"></div>
          <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
          <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        </div>

</div>
```

And I am currently satisfied with what it looks like on a desktop screen. However, I also need to make it look as on a picture below when the screen size is smaller than `770px` or when it breaks into a `col-xs-*` grid.

[image http://imageshack.com/a/img911/4395/WIt2nk.gif](http://imageshack.com/a/img911/4395/WIt2nk.gif)

However, on small screen the first row breaks as desired into 2 lines: line one two square images; line two one large. But the row 2 as displays on `desktop` picture breaks into three lines: square, large, square. While I need square, square, large. Similar goes to the third row as I need the large image to be the last. I was trying to play with css order property but it did not get my anywhere. I was also thinking about inserting extra `div`'s with `image`s and make them show up only on `xs` grid, but it seems to be an overkill. Don't have any other ideas and wondering if anyone have a tip. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Always think mobile first**

For this you have to use `push` and `pull`. So solution will be like this

```
<div class='container'>

        <div style='padding-bottom: 30px;' class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
          <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
          <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/840x400"></div>
        </div>

        <div style='padding-bottom: 30px;' class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>

          <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-push-6'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
          <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-pull-3'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/840x400"></div>
        </div>

        <div style='padding-bottom: 30px;' class='row'>

          <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-push-6'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
          <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-push-6'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
          <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-pull-6'><img style='max-width: 100%;'src="http://placehold.it/840x400"></div>
        </div>

</div>
```

So what actually I have done is that first I design it for `xs`/mobile screen ... then I use `push` and `pull` to adjust the `col` in `sm`, `md` and `lg` screens.

*P.S.* Better to use **`.img-responsive`** class instead of `style=max-width: 100%;`.

---

**Update- Bootstrap 4**

`order-*` and `.offset-*` are introduced in replacement of push pull classes using flexbox in Bootstrap 4. Like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 order-md-2">
        <div class="card card-body">RIGHT ALIGN</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 order-md-1">
        <div class="card card-body">LEFT ALIGN</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank. That is a great tip. I tried using your html and I looks like the desired effect on XS grid is achieved. But there's another problem, when you go bigger than XS the image in the second row with .col-sm-push-3 goes underneath the wide image. I tried playing around with push and pool but it was unsuccessful. Sorry I ma new to bootstrap. Do you think you could take a look at it?

Comment: This is great. I think now I got the idea how do pull and push classes work. Appreciate it