# How to switch element orders in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've looked many examples, but for some reason I can't get it to work myself.

I have 2 elements and I want them to be in 3 different positions for mobile, tablet and desktop view.

```
Desktop: [A] [B] -
Tablet: [A] - [B]
Mobile: - [B] -
        - [A] -
```

So for desktop I want the element A to float to left and B in the middle.
For Tablet I want A to float left and B to right.
And for Mobile I want to switch the order of A and B and be on top of each other.

Is this possible with just Bootstrap?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274372/bootstrap-css-layout-of-irregular-tiles-using-push-and-pull/28274649#28274649

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`col-push-*` could solve your problem:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-5 well">
        Content B
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-pull-5 well">
        Content A
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h4vdhnn2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, simple answer, I was trying to do something much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

find **[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/625271qh/)**

```
<div class="c b">b</div>
<div class="c a">a</div>
```

css:

```
    .c{
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
        border:1px solid #000;
    }
    .b{
        float:right;
        background:#eee;
    }
    .a{
        float:left;
        background:#ccc;
    }
    @media (max-width: 640px){
        .b{
            float:left;
        }
        .a{
            float:right;
        }
    }
```